# Redesigning Network

Tags: cisco, vlan, wireless

Kindly go through the current scenario and suggest me the best way to design the network.

Current Scenario:-
From ISP to modem to a Cisco 2900 Router.Then comes a 8 port switch and is then connected to a High Speed Internet Access(HSIA)Gateway.From the HSIA , it is connected Cisco 2900 Switch.It is then distributed to 4 switches via Fibre cable to 4 Cisco 2900 switches.Then around 150+ Access Points are connected to these switches which is responsible for providing internet to the guest.

The guests are unable to reach the internet most of the times and it is also seen that the Access Points (AP) are getting restarted themselves.There is no packet loss while connecting to the Modem directly and trying to ping any website.
The IPs are allocated via DHCP and there is a Access Point Controller for managing the AP. Kindly let me know if any further info required and help me to provide the best solution

Comment: You should include the make/model of your AP's and controller. You say you get packet loss, does your wifi remain connected? If so, do you get packet loss when pinging something internal (default gateway, server etc) or is it just packet loss when going out to the internet?

Comment: Do you have bandwidth monitoring on your links (especially the Internet link)?

Comment: When you say they restart, do you mean they reboot?  Could you have power problems?   You also need to reword your question.  As written, it's asking for the "best way," which leads to no end of opinions, and opinions are off-topic here.

Comment: 150 AP's?  Really?  Your talking 400,000 to 800,000 sq ft of WiFi coverage?  With 4 copper switches?  How are AP's physically connected, copper or fiber?  How are they powered?  Switch or Injector?  How is controller connected to LAN 1 or 2 links bundled or not?

Comment: @Mark :-
The switch which is present in the DataCenter is 
Catayst 2960-S Series POE+ 24 port.This is then distributed
to 4 48 port Catayst 2960-S Series POE+ via fibre cables.
The environment is a hotel with  Access point in each room.
It consists of total 150+ AP which is ditributed in 2 floors.
The access points are IPCom model (W30AP).

Comment: When the user tries to ping a website from the admin network ,
it reports a packet loss but when he pings a internal system , its fine.
The issue with the guest network is that the user gets disconnected from internet,
frequently and it was also observed that the AP also restarts automatically at times.

Comment: @Law29 :-No there is no bandwidth monitoring

Comment: @Ron Trunk :-
Yes i meant a restart.I can reword it as I am looking 
for a solution to the above mentioned issues.:)

Comment: @Ron Royston:-
As I said , its for Hotel and an Access point is placed in 
each room.The APs are connected to the switches via copper
and they are powered via PoE from the switch.
The controller is connected to the one of the 4 switches to 
which the APs are connected.

Comment: You really should monitor the bandwidth of your switch ports, that will help you in a lot of cases. As for APs rebooting, both "Ron"s have noted that it can very well be lack of power over the PoE, I can only agree.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

If your access points are continuously rebooting, it either means your switches can't supply enough power, or they can't communicate with the controller -- i.e., you don't have reliable network connectivity.  That could be wiring problems, or perhaps you have your switches daisy-chained and you are oversubscribing uplinks.

You can look at your interface counters to see if you see errors or drops.  That will give you a hint where to start looking.

Comment: :Thanks a lot ! Could you suggest some ways to do the same.How to check whether uplinks are being oversubscribed and to check the interface counters.I am new to the domain and I am preparing myself.The steps advised so far has helped me much

Comment: show interface x/y.  For example, show interface gigabit 0/1.  Look for errors or drops.

Answer (score 1):

- Turn down the volume (RF power) on each AP such that the size of each WiFi cell is limited to a single room (as best you can).  This is done via the controller.
- Set the minimum connection speed/bandwidth up higher to discourage clients from connecting to another rooms AP.
- Make sure your power is not oversubscribed.

> ```
>  Switch> show power inline
>  Available:370.0(w)  Used:80.6(w)  Remaining:289.4(w)
>
>  Interface Admin  Oper       Power   Device              Class Max
>                              (Watts)
>  --------- ------ ---------- ------- ------------------- ----- ----
>  Fa0/1     auto   on         6.3     IP Phone 7910       n/a   15.4
>  Fa0/2     static off        15.4    n/a                 n/a   15.4
>  Fa0/3     auto   on         6.3     IP Phone 7910       n/a   15.4
>  Fa0/4     auto   on         6.3     IP Phone 7960       2     15.4
>  Fa0/5     static on         15.4    IP Phone 7960       2     15.4
>  Fa0/6     static power-deny 10.0    n/a                 n/a   10.0
>  Fa0/7     auto   on         6.3     IP Phone 7910       n/a   15.4
> ```